# Filter out a table

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell

```
$d=$s.databases[$Database].Tables
```

`$d` contains every table of Database specified in `$Database`.
Now I need to pick a certain table by filtering it again.

```
 $d=$s.databases[$Database].Tables | where-object {$_.displayname -like $tables}
```

I run the code, but it giving null

Comment: Can we see some of the line from `$s.databases[$Database].Tables`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *curly brackets* for the `Where-Object` cmdlet or *omit* them and just write the property name:

```
$d=$s.databases[$Database].Tables | where-object displayname -like $tables
```

Comment: now,the error shows:  Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "displayname" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:26 char:49
+ $d=$s.databases[$Database].Tables | where-object <<<<  displayname -like $tables
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: actually I used curly braces ,now edited question..so it isnt the issue I guess

Comment: $tables = 'amount'   , name of a table of the database

Comment: He is running PowerShell 2.0 likely so curly are required.